# Usar links em formas geométricas

Tags: html, css, css3

Tenho o seguinte código:

```css
.menu .trapezioinvertido{
 float:left;
 border-top: 70px solid #c1c1c1;
 border-left: 30px solid transparent;
 border-right: 15px solid transparent;
 height: 0;
 width: 120px;
 color:#000;
 text-align: center;
 line-height:0px;
list-style-type:none;

}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
 <li><a class="trapezioinvertido" href="#">Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

Tenho um menu em que cada item será de uma diferente forma geométrica, este está nos li's.

Quero que o texto "Link" fique exatamente dentro do trapézio, o que posso fazer?

Comment: Você quer que o trapézio todo fique com o `href`, ou apenas o Link?

Comment: Tanto faz. Se não for mais difícil prefiro que o Link apenas fique com o href.

Comment: Alguém pode responder?

Comment: O Complicado é que seu elemento não tem altura (`height:0`), então vai ter que usar posição absoluta como o Randrade sugeriu.

Comment: Mesmo que eu atribua um height o texto não alinha no centro pois a forma é feita com border. Tem alguma solução?

Comment: Foi o que eu disse, e a resposta do Randrade é uma solução.

Answer (score 6):

Use a proposta do Randrade ou mude sua implementação.

Não tem como centralizar o link sem que a posição seja absoluta pois seu elemento **não possui altura** definida, você optou por fazer a parte visual com bordas e está aí dos problemas dessa abordagem. Tente responder: Como centralizar verticalmente um texto em um elemento sem altura?

Eu ainda apostaria no SVG. Criaria o link com a tag [**`<text>`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/SVG/Element/text) e agruparia os elementos (a figura geométrica e o link) com a tag [**`<g>`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/SVG/Element/g):

```css
svg { fill: #1dd2af }
svg text { fill: #fff }
svg text:hover { fill: #333 }
```

```html
<svg width='200' height='100'>
  
  <g id='figura-com-texto'>
    <polygon points='100,50 0,0 200,0 150,150' />
    <a xlink:href='http://pt.stackoverflow.com/'>
      <text x="70" y="30">StackOverflow</text>
    </a>
  </g>
  
</svg>
```

Comment: +1 pelo uso de `svg`. Eu também optaria em ir por esse caminho.

Comment: Eu também optaria

Comment: Leve, com suporte a animação e com controle total svg +1.

Answer (score 5):

Você pode colocar a classe `trapézioInvertido` em uma `div`, e chamar sua lista dentro da mesma.

```css
.trapezioinvertido{
 float:left;
 border-top: 70px solid #c1c1c1;
 border-left: 30px solid transparent;
 border-right: 15px solid transparent;
 height: 0;
 width: 120px;
 color:#000;
    line-height:0px; /* Remover esta linha caso quera mais de 1 item na lista ou aumentar o line-height*/
list-style-type:none;

}

.lista{
    position: absolute;   
    top:2%;
}
```

```html
<div class="trapezioinvertido">
    <ul class="lista">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li> 
        <!--<li><a href="#">Link1</a></li> -->
    </ul>
</div>
```

Criei a classe `lista` definindo a posição como `absolute` e a posição dele.

#### Edit

Para adicionar em uma lista, você deve adicionar `position: relative` na lista e alterar a posição de cada `<a href="#">`, desta forma:

```css
.trapezioinvertido{
    padding: 10px;
 border-top: 70px solid #c1c1c1;
 border-left: 30px solid transparent;
 border-right: 15px solid transparent;
 height: 0;
 width: 120px;
 color:#000;
 text-align: center;
 line-height:0px;
    list-style-type:none;
    position: relative;
}

li a.link{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 60px;
    left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
 <li class="trapezioinvertido" ><a href="#" class="link">Link</a></li>
    <li class="trapezioinvertido" ><a href="#" class="link">Link2</a></li>
    <li class="trapezioinvertido" ><a href="#" class="link">Link3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Para entender melhor as `positions`, [veja esta resposta.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/38217/20615)

Comment: Isto nao vai me atrapalhar de nenhuma forma no decorrer do código e da página? Me refiro ao position absolute e fazer um menu com divs ao invés de li's e a's como de costume. Pois vou ter outros itens no menu que irão ter outras formas, não é apenas esta.

Comment: @TiagoP.C Você não explicou para o que seria o menu. Se cada `li` for uma forma geométrica, essa não é a melhor abordagem, e caso for isso, edite sua pergunta com essas informações, que elaboro uma resposta mais adequada.

Comment: Editei a pergunta @Randrade

Comment: @TiagoP.C Veja se essa edição lhe atende.

Comment: Acontece que eu vou ter que colocar outro item do menu com outra forma do lado, aí não vai dar certo!

Comment: @TiagoP.C Edite sua pergunta e coloque todas as informações necessárias que você precisa, para que eu possa lhe ajudar.