# Trapézio com CSS ou JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, css3

Olá, preciso fazer um trapézio, dessa forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Que seja feito com CSS ou JS. Mas não pode ser feito com borders, pois assim não funciona bem se eu precisar colocar algum texto dentro, também não posso usar nenhum position absolute ou algo do tipo, pois trata-se de um menu com diferentes formas, então não posso comprometer os outros elementos. Aguardo ajuda.

Comment: Você tentou a solução que eu propus na outra pergunta?

Comment: Sim @CelsomTrindade, e funcionaria do jeito que eu preciso, mas como você disse lá vai ser de difícil manutenção e manipulação depois, o que eu infelizmente não posso fazer.

Comment: Esta pergunta parece já ter resposta aqui: [Usar links em formas geométricas](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/100126). Outra solução seria utilizar imagens já prontas com a forma desejada e utiliza-las como `background-image`. Desta maneira podes trabalhar melhor na sua responsividade.

Comment: Não é "incorreto" usar imagens ao invés de estilizar formas?

Comment: Nem sempre. Tudo depende da sua necessidade e capacidade de gerar o conteúdo. No seu caso, você tem restrições muito complexas e necessita obter o resultado. A imagem pode ser uma solução simples, mas com uma contra-partida de aumentar o tempo de load. Já utilizando as bordas, você tem o lado negativo de restringir o alinhamento. E assim por diante.

Comment: não vejo por que proibir `position: absolute`, talvez você apenas não tenha pensando em como usa-lo de forma à atenda as suas necessidades, pegue por exemplo este [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6b7pbnwy/1/)... apesar do uso do `position: absolute`, a `div.conteudo` assume a mesma forma da `div.trapezio` e não possui nenhum estilo que "dê forma" a mesma... enquanto que o trapezio é desenhado pelas `div.esquerda`, `div.direita` e `div.centro`, porem estas não tem conteudo e ficam por tras da `div.conteudo`.