# Div diagonais mosaico em CSS

Tags: html, css

Preciso criar um menu com div diagonais que quando passa o mause em cima troca de cor e cada imagem contem um link para uma categoria diferente.

O problema é que eu não consigo criar uma div em diagonal, e queria achar uma solução para o problema apenas usando html e css se possível.

Como posso criar um menu mosaico como este?

No caso apenas fazer formas geométricas não funciona para mim, pois tem o background image.

Preciso distorcer o tamanho das divs para ficar semelhante a imagem.

Um pessoal está falando que é duplicata e até mesmo votando contra meu post, por isto irei mostrar que o problema não é tão simples. O problema é muito mais a fundo que as formas geométricas por que no esquema de **border** não dá para fazer um background image. Apenas adicionar uma cor de fundo.

E pelo skew dá para colocar um background-image, porém não consigo fazer as imagens ter o ângulo correto, pois ela distorce os dois lados do ângulo.

```css
#trapezoid { 
  border-top: 200px solid transparent;
  border-left: 0px solid white;
  border-right: 40px solid white;
  width: 150px;
  float: left;

  background-image: url('http://pongnamuroms.weebly.com/uploads/1/3/3/6/13369650/144214_orig.png');
  opacity: 0.7;
  background-size: calc(100% + 100px);
}

#trapezoid2 { 
  border-bottom: 200px solid transparent;
  border-left: 40px solid white;
  border-right: 0px solid white;
  width: 150px;
  margin-left: -34px;
  float: left;

  background-image: url('http://www.androidspin.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/flow_aquablue.png');
  opacity: 0.7;
  background-size: calc(100% + 100px);
}

#trapezoid2:hover{
  opacity: 1;
}

#trapezoid:hover{
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="trapezoid">

</div>
<div id="trapezoid2">
</div>

<div id="trapezoid3">

</div>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tem essas duas perguntas: [Como criar formas geométricas usando CSS?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100110/4808) e [Como usar links em formas geométricas?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100126/4808).

Comment: @renan até cheguei a pensar em votar nelas como sendo a mesma coisa, mas com imagem de fundo a coisa muda um pouco. As técnicas mencionadas lá funcionam para cores sólidas. Border e Skew são problemáticas com imagens de fundo. SVG é uma possibilidade, mas como tem coisas escritas dentro, não basta fazer meros polígonos. Chego a pensar que aqui cabe uma resposta bem diferente das dos links indicados.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

segue um exemplo usando SVG

```js
var trapezio1 = document.getElementById("trapezio1");
var trapezio2 = document.getElementById("trapezio2");

trapezio1.addEventListener("click", function () {
  alert("Parque");
});

trapezio2.addEventListener("click", function () {
  alert("Praia");
});
```

```css
.trapezio {  
  stroke:black;
  stroke-width:1;
  filter:url("#desaturate")
}

#trapezio1 {
  fill:url(#img1);        
}

#trapezio2 {
  fill:url(#img2);
}

.trapezio:hover  {
  filter: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 455 250" >
  <polygon id="trapezio1" class="trapezio" points="  0,0 250,0 200,250   0,250" />
  <polygon id="trapezio2" class="trapezio" points="255,0 455,0 455,250 205,250" />      
  <defs>
    <pattern id="img1" width="1" height="1">
      <image xlink:href="http://crossorigin.me/http://www.travelandleisure.com/sites/default/files/field/image/local-experts-shanghai-most-beautiful-parks.jpg" 
             width="250" height="250" />
    </pattern>
    <pattern id="img2" width="1" height="1">
      <image xlink:href="http://crossorigin.me/http://www.travelandleisure.com/sites/default/files/field/image/local-experts-bangkok-best-beaches.jpg" 
             width="250" height="250"/>
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <filter id="desaturate">
    <feColorMatrix type="matrix" 
                   values="0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0
                           0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0
                           0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0
                           0      0      0      1 0"/>
  </filter>
</svg>
```

Comment: Interessante, essa solução cai como uma luva pro autor do tópico. Muito bom!

Comment: fiz um alteração para utilizar viewbox no lugar de viewport, desta forma fica mais facil manipular o tamanho do svg e manter as proporções.

Comment: Tem como colocar as imagens em tons de cinza, e quando passar por cima colorir?

Comment: @FelipeJorge, apliquei um filtro para colocar a imagem em escala de cinza.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode se interessar pelo método skew do css3. Digamos que você pode "enviesar" sua div de acordo com suas preferências:

Eu tenho minha div:

```
<div id="divteste">olá mundo</div>
```

E minha folha de estilos:

```
div {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: yellow;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

div#divteste {
    -ms-transform: skew(20deg,10deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: skew(20deg,10deg); /* Safari */
    transform: skew(20deg,10deg); /* Standard syntax */
}
```

Exemplo no JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sab09dfq/2/

Mais sobre o método skew: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp

Já mudar a cor ao passar o mouse, você quer saber mais sobre o hover. Pode ser feito tanto no css, como no js.

Mais sobre o seletor hover: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp

Comment: Teria como colocar imagem de fundo nos seus exemplos pra validar a técnica? Um problema no seu fiddle que eu notei logo de início é a distorção do texto.

Comment: Olá Bacco, de fato o skew vai distorcer o conteúdo todo da div, incluindo a imagem de fundo. Há uma forma de contornar isso se você aplica o skew invertido no texto da div por exemplo:

https://jsfiddle.net/7qhgaw6u/

Comment: Faltou o display:block no .texto - De qualquer forma, acho que essa solução não vai servir pro caso do autor, pq nao daria pra fazer "unskew" no fundo. Essa solução do skew já tinha sido apresentada em outra questão, mas não tinha imagem nos requisitos: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100110/70 - Uma alternativa seria fazer um _clip_ na div, mas é aceito por poucos browsers. http://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path

Comment: Servir serve, mas no caso o autor vai ter que criar um pseudo elemento contendo a imagem, como neste tópico:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18289643/how-do-i-unskew-background-image-in-skewed-layer-css

O Fiddle com a imagem sem distorção na div com skew aplicado.:
http://jsfiddle.net/qNW8j/177/
http://jsfiddle.net/qNW8j/177/

Comment: Se vc postar algo nessa linha pode valorizar a resposta um bocado. A propósito, vc pode usar os _snippets_ do próprio SOpt se quiser, pro demo ficar na resposta. O bom do pseudo-elemento é que aí já pode por a imagem e o texto, pra tirar a distorção junto. Mesmo assim, vai ter que fazer umas peripécias no caso de imagens trapezoidais.

Comment: Mas no caso não dá para deixar um dos angulos retos e outros tortos como no exemplo das imagens? Por que no caso do exemplo que você deu os dois lados se distorcem, mas nas imagens a cima as vezes é só um lado que tem que se distorcer.

Comment: O skew trabalha com os eixos x e y, você pode controlar os dois 

transform: (10deg, -25deg);

No fim das contas talvez o Bacco tenha razão, essa não seja a solução mais adequada para o seu problema. E se você recortar os backgrounds das divs e ao invés de trabalhar a forma da div, simplesmente sobrepor as divs com os backgrounds recortados através do z-index?

Comment: O problema serio o hover, que ele não ficaria certo para todas as divs, pois uma div iria sobrepor a aoutra.