# Estilização de div em CSS

Tags: html, css, front-end

Eu gostaria de saber como é possível personalizar a div para deixá-la "atravessada", assim como na imagem abaixo, onde o top-left e o bottom-left da div laranja ficam meio que cortados.

[image: Perceba a que o a div laranja fica meio que "atravessada" na página]

Comment: Aqui tem a solução pronta, basta aplicar na vertical: [Como criar formas geométricas usando CSS](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/100110/como-criar-formas-geom%c3%a9tricas-usando-css)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode fazer dessa maneira:

```css
            .trap_section{
                position: relative;
                width: 500px;
                border: none;
                margin-top: 100px;
            }
            #trap_top1{
                position: absolute;
                top: -80px;
                border-top: 80px solid transparent;
                border-right-width: 500px; border-right-style: solid; border-right-color: rgb(255, 137, 91);
            }
            #trap_bottom1{    
                position: absolute;
                bottom: -80px;
                border-bottom: 80px solid transparent;
                border-right-width: 500px; border-right-style: solid; border-right-color: rgb(255, 137, 91);
            }
            #section1{
                background: #FF895B;
                color: #FFFFFF;
                margin: 0 auto;
                overflow-y: hidden;
                height: 200px;
            }
            h1, p{text-align:center;}
```

```html
    <div class="trap_section">
        <div id="trap_top1" style=""></div>
        <div id="section1">
          <div class="indent">
            <div>
              <h1>MEU TÍTULO</h1>
              <p>MEU CONTEÚDO</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="trap_bottom1" style=""></div>
    </div>
```